# Temp Pointers: Correct malloc and free

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

My idea was to declare a char *temp pointer at the very beginning of my function that can be used over and over again.

At first, I used malloc at the very beginning and free() at the very end. The problem was that the first string I copied to temp was the longest of all the strings. So when I printed the strings that followed the first one the end of the first string was still there:
E.g.
First string was "hello", the next was "no"
-> I wrote temp into a FILE and the result was nollo

To solve the problem I decided to use free() each time after I wrote the string to my file in order to free the storage for the next string. This caused the error "error for object 0x7fe274801000: pointer being freed was not allocated".

So neither of my ideas worked... What is the best way to handle this? Thanks!!

```
void hexdump (FILE *output, char *buffer, int length){
int offset = 0;
int rows = (length%16)==0 ? (length/16) : ((length/16)+1);
char *temp = (char *)malloc(MAX_OUTPUT);

for(int j = 0; j<rows; j++){
    offset = offset + 16;
    sprintf(temp, "%06x : ", offset);
    fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
    printf("%06x : ", offset);
    free(temp);
    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++){
        if ((j == rows-1) && (!buffer[i+(j*16)])){
            strcpy(temp,"   ");
            fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
            printf("   ");
            free(temp);
        } else {
        sprintf(temp, "%02x ", buffer[i+(j*16)]);
        fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
        printf("%02x ", buffer[i+(j*16)]);
        free(temp);
        }
    }
    strcpy(temp, "  ");
    fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
    printf("  ");
    free(temp);
    for(int n = 0; n<16; n++){
        if ((j == rows-1) && (!buffer[n+(j*16)])){
            strcpy(temp, " ");
            fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
            printf(" ");
            free(temp);
        } else {
                if((buffer[n+(j*16)]>31) && (buffer[n+(j*16)]<127)){
                sprintf(temp, "%c", buffer[n+(j*16)]);
                fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
                printf("%c", buffer[n+(j*16)]);
                free(temp);
            } else {
                strcpy(temp, ".");
                fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
                printf(".");
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(temp, "\n");
    fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
    printf("\n");
    free(temp);

}

}
```

The printf output works correctly while the output file does not..

Comment: Turn your idea into some code.

Comment: The problem probably has more to do with how you're writing to the file.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I uploaded my code now. see above

Comment: Yes, it can be reused. But not after `free(temp);`

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` is wrong - that gives you the size of the pointer. For this case you probably want `strlen(temp)`.

Comment: If you get "nollo" it's because when you put "no" into your buffer your didn't also put in a terminating zero.

Comment: Rather than free what you would prefer to do is to clear the buffer.  Something like memset(temp, 0, MAX_OUTPUT);  And free at the end.  free does not clear the buffer, it simply releases the storage for other uses

Comment: got it!! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `free` memory that a pointer points to, it is no longer valid to use.  You would need to call `malloc` again to get a valid block of memory.  But even if you did that, the real problem is that you're not writing the proper amount.

All of your writes look like this:

```
fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
```

Here, `sizeof(temp)` is **not** the length of the string contained in `temp`, but the size of `temp`, which is a pointer and most likely either 4 or 8.

Use `strlen` instead, which gives you the length of the string:

```
fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), strlen(temp), output);
```

Or better yet, just to `fprint` to write to the file instead of `sprintf` followed by `fwrite`.  For example, change this:

```
sprintf(temp, "%06x : ", offset);
fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), sizeof(temp), output);
```

To this:

```
fprintf(output, "%06x : ", offset);
```

Then you can get rid of `temp` and the associated `malloc` and `free` calls entirely.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I will use fprintf from now on. for the parts with no need to format temp: can i also use fprintf over there? 
Like for example here:
strcpy(temp, "  ");
fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), strlen(temp), output);

Comment: @wolverine Yes, just use `fprintf(output, " ")`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `realloc()` on `temp`.

```
char *temp = malloc(size);
//Do some stuff with temp
temp = realloc(temp, newSize);//instead of free(temp);
//Clear the string (fill it with \0) if you want to have a proper new string.
//Do some stuff, and so on until :
free(temp);
//Eventually some more code, WITHOUT using temp
return();
```

`realloc(ptr, val);` is like `free(ptr); ptr = malloc(val);`

Hope it helps you !

### EDIT:

I know the OP has already been solved, it's just another possible solution.